# Can someone explain this one line of code?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, declaration

```
 public static int fiveOfaKind(int dice[]){
```

Obviously it is declaring a method but what I'm confused about is the part that goes "(int dice[])"

dice is an integer array that was declared in the main method.

What does that bit in the parenthesis do? And what is it called, I want to look it up and read about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a parameter for the method. The dice array declared in the main method is in a different scope and unrelated to this method.

```
public static void printArr(int arr[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] dice = new int[5];
    ...


    foo(dice);
}
```

In this example you have a method that takes an array and prints the elements in it. In the main method you pass this array to the method as a parameter.

https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_methods_param.asp

Answer (score 0):

> What does that bit in the parenthesis do?

It requires that it is an array of variable length.

> what is it called

Square brackets

Hope that helps...